# Storing Huge Amount of Data from XML to MYSQL database for PDF

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I need an advice to convert XML data to pdf format using php. I want to provide am option to download pdf whenever the download link is clicked.

I have an XML file that contains thousand of records.I want to convert my XML records into pdf format. Previously, I used to generate pdfs from mysql. I don't know how I can convert my xml data directly to pdf using php.

One option is to retrieve each and every XML record one by one and insert it into the database using php and mysql.

**My question is :**

**Wont it be less efficient if I will *Parse xml record and run mysql insert statement* thousand of times to store thousand of records into the database ?**

Also,more time would be required to retrieve those records from the database to generate pdf. Is there any other way around to deal with this problem efficiently and effectively ? Please suggest me .

Comment: "thousand of records" is not a "huge amount data". What would do in the case of millions of records?

Comment: consider not doing this with XML->PHP->PDF but with https://xmlgraphics.apache.org/fop/

Comment: Wouldn't it pay to convert the XML file to a PDF once, then either store the location of the PDF in a database or create a predictable link based upon the name of the XML file. This way no database is needed. Don't over complicate the job

Answer (score 0):

The weakest link here is XML parser - that usually is the slowest and the most memory consuming process, so I would export the XML to MySQL database and then generate PDF reports on demand.
But that would only make sense if you need generate PDFs dynamically on user request. Otherwise it is better to convert XML to PDF once and keep static files on the server.

One of the most popular PDF engine used in PHP world is http://www.tcpdf.org/